# JUnit error from other branch is shown in current branch

Tags: java, testing, junit, branch

I've got a wired problem. I've written a JUnit test in an older branch. In this JUnit test, some tests failed so I've fixed them. Now I'm in a new branch and sometimes I run the test, I got the same error as in the old branch in a totally different (or new) JUnit test. 
I deleted the git repository, the workspace, Tomcat (everything) and cleared the cache of eclipse and cleared the project (also Maven clean) and the problem still occurs. 
Ah, the test is no simple Unit tests, this is system tests, so we need a database and server and so on.

Do anybody know this problem or got a solution for this?

Comment: Since your tests have got external dependencies I suspect the `setup & teardown`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But the setup and teardown could not be the problem. On the computers of my workmates the same test works fine, also on the jenkins server.